# MySQL Server 5.5: Uninstaller gone missing - how to uninstall while preserving data and settings?

Tags: mysql, uninstall, installer

I'm running MySQL Server 5.5.25 64-bit on a Windows 7 machine.

Recently I wanted to upgrade to the latest 5.5.28 version, but the installer wouldn't recognize the installed instance.

I then noticed that there's no uninstaller (anymore?) under Add/Remove programs, although the server itself is running fine.

I'd like to uninstall the server manually and then install the new version, but without putting the data or configuration at risk.

Can you please advise how to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the uninstaller not showing up under Add/Remove programs was that MySQL server had been installed under another user account. Switching to that user account, I was able to uninstall or upgrade my installation.